# Training data comprised of matrix transpose

Tags: matrix

I'm reading "An Introduction to Statistical Learning," and am confused about one sentence, highlighted in the screen shot below.

I may be interpreting this incorrectly, but I am reading the "T" at the end of the sentence to mean the transpose of the vector $x_i$. Is this correct? If it is correct, why is referencing the transpose necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the transpose. The reason why it is necessary is that vectors are commonly defined as column vectors, i.e. as matrices of dimension n x 1 (nr. of rows x nr. of columns). I.e. a vector $v=\{v_1...v_w\}$ would commonly be assumed to be of dimension w x 1. However, in the majority of statistic literature, a data matrix $X$ is built so that the observations are sorted by rows and the variables are sorted by columns. Hence, your vector $x_i$, which represents the data from the $i$th observation, needs to be a row vector, and thus needs to be transposed since simply defining it as $x_i=\{x_{i1}...x_{ip}\}$ would mean it's a column vector.